# Problem moving database to new server

Tags: mysql, permissions

I am currently running into two problems. First, when viewing tables using MySQL Query Browser, it keeps displaying "Could not fetch columns".  [image: Could not fetch rows]

Second, when attempting to go in an edit any of the fields, the "Edit" button is greyed out and won't allow me to modify anything in the table.

My first thought is that this is a permissions issue, so let me give some background on where I've come so far.  Overall goal, create a backup PrestaShop on another server for dev work.  Both servers are running CentOS 6.2 and MySQL Server 5.1.73.
Steps I've taken in this process (specifically in regards to the db):
1. Ran mysqldump -u root -p --databases shop > shop.sql
2. Copied shop.sql over to the new server
3. Made sure MySQL was installed and running on new server
4. Ran mysql -u root -p shop < shop.sql
5. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*Whatever*' WITH GRANT OPTION 
6. I made sure to setup a user with the same permission as on the previous server as well to try to reduce problems and granted the same privileges to it.

So now I can view and run select statements on the data, but it is not allowing me to edit the fields from within query browser.  I am able to log in and run update statements from the command line on the local host through putty, however.  Any thoughts or ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: First step... Inside query browser, run the query `SHOW GRANTS;` to be certain you have actually connected with the credentials you used at the login dialog, and that you have the permissions you expect to have.

Comment: Yes, I've double checked all the users that I've setup and the each have all privileges on *.*.

Comment: Right, but did you also verify that you are actually logging in as the user that you believe you're logging in as?  Next step, the MySQL error log... particularly any errors or warnings on startup related to the system grant tables.  Especially if you have copied this data from an older version of MySQL Server.

Comment: Ok, oddest thing I've ever seen.  I let the server sit there for the weekend and now it is registering the databases perfectly fine and both problem are solved.  There have been no reboots or other changes made.  Maybe there were some permission grants that just took a while to propagate through the system.